# Sorting by several columns in different order using meta-search gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, meta-search

I'm using meta-search gem for searching and ordering columns.
This code will order records only in one direction:

```
scope_name.search('meta_sort' => 'name_and_status.desc')
```

How can I sort columns in different directions? E.g.

```
scope_name.search('meta_sort' => 'name.asc_and_status.desc')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

meta_search only allow one direction of sort. You can just use order after search.

```
scope_name.search(params[:search]).order('name, status desc')
```

If you use the sort_link in the page, you can specify the order in the page. But I havn't used this.

```
scope_name.search('meta_sort' => 'name_and_status.desc')

<%= sort_link @search, :name, "Name", :default_order => :asc %>
<%= sort_link @search, :status, "Status", :default_order => :desc %>
```